# Contact Android device through a Server

Tags: android

Is there any way to send request from a server to an Android phone? Actually, I want to control an application (enable or disable some features of the application) in an Android phone by a server. Can I use the IP Address of the Android device?. Can anyone guide me.
Thank you!.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the above option is not suited for your case then you can create a simple service
for your application and then attach to application.

The service can be a thread which sends requests to the server with some time intervals that you find suitable and can check if there is anything to check and to do for the application.
And also can run in background.

Comment: Thanks for the comment!. Sending request periodically will not affect seriously to the battery life of the device?

Comment: It depends on your thread control actually.If the time interval is not too frequent like 1-2 secs then you'll be okay.I actually use this technique for one of my projects and i'm sending a request to a server every 5 mins or so and controlling the thread if there is not net connection or so i'm sleeping the thread which will reduce the consumption and the consumption is really really little for that thread if you control it well. It wont effect the battery life that you can be aware of.

Answer (score 3):

Much simpler way is for phone to contact server and ask should features be enabled. You could also use something like this http://code.google.com/android/c2dm/ but I'm not sure if this is an overkill for your use case.

Comment: Thanks for the response sir!
Actually, I want to enable specific features when the user of the server enables it. So, the phone cannot sent HTTP request all the time.It will caused to reduce the battery life of the phone. Am I correct?

Comment: If you don't do it often it shouldn't be a problem, also take into consideration the amount of data being sent/received since for some users mobile data can be expensive.

Answer (score 2):

All push services are usually implemented as well concealed polling.  Phones on 3G networks usually sit behind  NAT proxies and are not visible to outside world. The same holds for most wlan networks - so either use C2DM, or write your own service   polling config information from some server provided by you